# Higher degree polynomial with complex roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm working on the following problem:

$$ r^4 - 3r^2 -4r = 0 $$

I factor out one $r$ and leaving me $ r(r^3 - 3r -4) = 0 $. One real root is $r=0$, and I'm unable to find the other ones. I tried using synthetic division but it didn't help. I tried googling synthetic division with complex root problems, but all the videos use examples that are given a complex solution in order to solve the other roots. So what could be a good approach in this problem?

Comment: This might interest you: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks, good readings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Applying *Cardano's formula* (see the link above) to the reduced equation
$$
r^3 - 3r -4=0,
$$ one gets the real root

> $$
> r_1=\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}+\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}
> $$

and the two complex roots

> $$
> r_{2}^{\pm}=-\frac12 \left(2- \sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3} \left(1\pm i \sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}\left(1\mp i \sqrt{3}\right) .
> $$